# How to dismiss showMenu popup by any user action outside the popup

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, popup, flutter-layout

I am using [showMenu](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showMenu.html) function for displaying the pop up. Although it works without any issues, user has to tap outside of the popup to dismiss it.

This is how I implemented it.

```
    //for showing  the pop up on click of the menu
    GestureDetector(
            child: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
              _showPopupMenu(context, details.globalPosition);
            }),

 
    //show menu
    _showPopupMenu(BuildContext context, Offset offset) async{
    double left = offset.dx;
    double top = offset.dy;
    await showMenu(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 16, 0),
        useRootNavigator: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
      items: [
        PopUpMenuItem(some child),
        PopUpMenuItem(some child),
        PopUpMenuItem(some child),
        ]
      ); 
      }
```

How can I dismiss the pop up, not only by tap, also by any kind of user actions which is happening outside the pop up area?

Comment: I don't understand.. ShowMenu is dismissed automatically when taped outside of the menu area.. In matter of fact I've just tested it just to be sure and it works. so what is your question? what other user actions do you mean?

Comment: Correct. It works perfectly. But incase of a scroll view, user might try to scroll up or down( could be swipe actions), intending to dismiss the popup. I am trying to implement this. Please let me know, if any more information is needed on this.

Comment: I can tell for sure but I believe if the user will try to scroll while showmenu is visible on physical device then it will be dismissed. try it on physical device

Comment: I tried on Android phone. But had to tap the screen to dismiss it. I am not sure,if I am missing anything. I went through the documentation,but couldn't find anything useful though. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I still don't get it.. Why would user want to scroll something with open menu? If he open something then he needs to close it to do other interaction with the app. It is like wanting to scroll something behind dialog window open...